# What is the proper way to add a case when statement to avoid getting a division by zero error in Postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

This is my original code:

```
    --summarize traffic for the clusters
    select cluster, count(*) as stories, sum(bbrefs) as bbrefs, 
    sum(socialrefs) as socialrefs, avg (uvs) as uvs, 
    1+sum(socialrefs)/sum(cast(bbrefs as decimal(18,2))) as vrlift
    into retirecalculate
    from joinreftraffic
    group by cluster
```

My error is as follows: 
         ERROR:  division by zero

```
    ********** Error **********

    ERROR: division by zero
    SQL state: 22012
```

My first attempt to a solution gave ma a syntax error. The code is below:

```
    --summarize traffic for the clusters
    select cluster, count(*) as stories, sum(bbrefs) as bbrefs, 
    sum(socialrefs) as socialrefs, avg (uvs) as uvs, 
    1+sum(socialrefs)/NULLIF(sum(cast(bbrefs as decimal(18,2)), 0)) as 
    vrlift
    into retirecalculate
    from joinreftraffic
    group by cluster
```

My second attempt at a solution also gave me a syntax error. The code is as follows.

```
    --summarize traffic for the clusters
    select cluster, count(*) as stories, sum(bbrefs) as bbrefs, 
    sum(socialrefs) as socialrefs, avg (uvs) as uvs, 
    CASE WHEN sum(cast(bbrefs as decimal(18, 2))) >0 THEN 
    1+sum(socialrefs)/sum(cast(bbrefs as decimal(18,2))) ELSE NULL END AS as 
    vrlift
    into retirecalculate
    from joinreftraffic
    group by cluster
```

What am I doing wrong? What is the correct way to avoid the division by error?

Comment: Case _expression_...

Comment: i think the second query should work..you have 2 `as`,before `vrlift` in the query.

Comment: @jarlh you have the power to fix it...

Answer (score 0):

Your last expression looks correct, except that you have duplicated the word "as".

It should be:

```
--summarize traffic for the clusters
select cluster, count(*) as stories, sum(bbrefs) as bbrefs, 
sum(socialrefs) as socialrefs, avg (uvs) as uvs, 
CASE WHEN sum(cast(bbrefs as decimal(18, 2))) >0 THEN 
1+sum(socialrefs)/sum(cast(bbrefs as decimal(18,2))) ELSE NULL END as 
vrlift
into retirecalculate
from joinreftraffic
group by cluster
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `nullif()`

```
create table retirecalculate
as
select cluster, 
       count(*) as stories, 
       sum(bbrefs) as bbrefs, 
       sum(socialrefs) as socialrefs, 
       avg (uvs) as uvs, 
       1 + sum(socialrefs)/nullif(sum(bbrefs)::decimal),0) as vrlift
from joinreftraffic
group by cluster;
```

---

I also changed the code to use the standard `CREATE TABLE AS` instead of the discouraged `select ... into`